# Custom JavaScript prompts in iOS using PhoneGap HTML

Tags: javascript, html, ios, cordova

My app has a couple of JS prompts and it seems to always display the page name like.

index.html

Is there a way to change the index.html to my App's name or custom text.

Example:

My App // Which replaces .index.html
var name=prompt("I am an prompt box!");

Answer (score 2):

you can use the following code

```
navigator.notification.confirm(
                'My custom message',    // message
                myCallbackFunc,         // callback with index of button pressed
                'Header - App Name',    // title
                'btn1, btn2'            // buttonLabels
   );
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap/Cordova apps are as much as the user interface is concerned mainly Html and Javascript. And the app's name you are referring to is in fact the title of your main Html file (index.html).

To change that you can either:

A) Change the Html of your index.html file and set the  element

B) Or from your Javascript code with document.title="new title".